# Is it possible to create the growing flower effect with easeljs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

I am trying to create a html5 game for touch devices with easeljs. One of the effects I'm trying to accomplish is when the player swipes up on the screen, a flower grows up dynamically (randomly) for a butterfly to rest on.

Is it possible to do that with easeljs? Thanks.

Examples:

http://onecm.com/projects/canopy/

http://www.openrise.com/lab/FlowerPower/

Comment: Have you looked into animating object scaling? In [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com), for example, you would just call `yourObject.animate({ scaleX: 2, scaleY: 2 }, { duration: 500, onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas) });` to animate object size.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I was originally thinking about making the growing of the flower seem organic, but that seems to be too complicated. Using sprite might also work, but I also worry about the file size. So, now I think your suggestion is the best solution (better finish the project before the deadline).